# Extracting strings from a physical drive

Tags: python, computer-forensics

I'm looking to write a script in Python 2.x that will scan physical drive (physical and not logical) for specific strings of text that will range in size (chat artifacts). I have my headers and footers for the strings and so I am just wondering how is best to scan through the drive? My concern is that if I split it into, say 250MB chunks and read this data into RAM before parsing through it for the header and footer, it may be the header is there but the footer is in the next chunk of 250MB.

So in essence, I want to scan PhysicalDevice0 for strings starting with "ABC" for example and ending in "XYZ" and copy all content from within. I'm unsure whether to scan the data as ascii or Hex too.

As drives get bigger, I'm looking to do this in the quickest manner possible.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What platform are you working on?

Comment: it's basically buffered reading where likely you want to avoid to check if you are at the end of the buffer at each read-a-byte. You can e.g. read 250 Mbyte, scan until end_of_buffer - length_of_the_string to be found, and then load the next 250 Mbytes - length of the string (so, the reading overlaps of N bytes where N is the length of the string you are searching for). Special care is needed on the boundary: if a partial match is on the run, you "delay" the loading of the next (overlapped) chunk, or return Found if you complete the match

Comment: I'd like it to run on multiple platforms if possible but most majority of computers will be running Windows 7 x64

Comment: Take a look at hachoir, https://bitbucket.org/haypo/hachoir/wiki/Home, it has some similar tools already and provides a great framework for building your own.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem can be formulated as "how do I search in a very long file with no line structure." It's no different from what you'd do if you were reading line-oriented text one line at a time: Imagine you're reading a text file block by block, but have a line-oriented regexp to search with; you'd search up to the last *complete* line in the block you've read, then hold on to the final incomplete line and read another block to extend it with. So, you don't start afresh with each new block read. Think of it as a sliding window; you only advance it to discard the parts you were able to search completely.

Do the same here: write your code so that the strings you're matching never hit the edge of the buffer. E.g., if the header you're searching for is 100 bytes long: read a block of text; check if the *complete* pattern appears in the block; advance your reading window to 100 bytes before the end of the current block, and add a new block's worth of text after it. Now you can search for the header without the risk of missing it. Once you find it, you're extracting text until you see the stop pattern (the footer). It doesn't matter if it's in the same block or five blocks later: your code should know that it's in extracting mode until the stop pattern is seen.